# Setting the size of Div to be the same as its Child (before the child loads)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent div `.photo_container` that holds an `img`, and stretches to the dimensions of this `img` with its `display: inline-block` CSS attribute.

**Problem:** Because there will be many `.photo_container` divs on the page and the images take some time to load, before all the `img` loads, the page will be filled with the tiny unstretched divs (with a few px of padding) before expanding to accomodate each `img` as they load one by one.

Is it possible to 'pre-stretch' the divs to the correct size so that when its child `img` loads, it does not have to change its size?

Here's an illustration of how it looks like before the images load (ugly!) and after.

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="photo_box">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know what exactly the dimensions of those images are before they finished loading? Do you know that information beforehand?

Comment: jQuery cannot know what size the image is until the image starts to load. if you keep the container element hidden until its image loads, at least you won't see the tiny unstretched container box

Comment: I can know the image dimensions before the image loads by storing its dimension in the database on the serverside... If I retrieve their width and height and insert into `<img src="..." width="..." height="..." />`, would it help?

Comment: @Nyxynyx if you have the image dimensions, and add them as attributes to the `img` then the browser should sort out the layout even before the images load.

Comment: @Nyxynyx after some testing, seems like that is browser dependent. Safari sizes the boxes based on the img size, but Firefox doesn't seem to.

Comment: @steveax does that mean that I'll get tiny boxes in Firefox before the img loads? In this case, I'm thinking of placing transparent .png (they load pretty fast) (with z-index below the actual img) the size of the img so that the containers will be of the correct size before the actual img loads

Comment: @steveax Just tested in Chrome (win), Firefox(win), Chrome(mac), Fireefox(mac), Safari(mac), getting the img dimensions from backend and setting the img attr worked nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know image dimension unless you actually load the image (in JS or CSS alike). So it doesn't matter if you use JS and set container dimensions dynamically - you still need to load image first and thus for some time you will display the "ugly" empty containers.

So, add minimum size to .photo_container. I looks like at least width of all your thumbs is consistent, so do something like `.photo_container { min-width:100px; min-height:50px }`. Then to each image add an onLoad callback that will resize parent accordingly.

If you use jQuery, do something like this:

```
$('.photo_container img').each(function() {
  $(this).bind('load', function() {
    var w = $(this).width(),
        h = $(this).height();
    $(this).parent('.photo_container').attr({ width: w+'px', height: h+'px' });
  }
});
```

Comment: By the time the image loads, the browser should just handle things - perhaps better to just loop through `.photo_container img` and set the dimensions rather than waiting for the load event to fire.

Comment: Well exactly. This code is in needed in case you used min-width / min-height if they are different (expecially, larger) than the images.